# User with assigned policy can't access secrets in KV version 2

Tags: hashicorp-vault

I have created a kv (version 2) secrets engine, mounted on /secret:

```
$ vault secrets list
Path          Type         Accessor              Description
----          ----         --------              -----------
cubbyhole/    cubbyhole    cubbyhole_915b3383    per-token private secret storage
identity/     identity     identity_9736df92     identity store
secret/       kv           kv_8ba16621           n/a
sys/          system       system_357a0e34       system endpoints used for control, policy and debugging
```

I have created a policy that should give admin access to everything in `myproject`:

```
$ vault policy read myproject
path "secret/myproject/*" {
  capabilities = ["create","read","update","delete","list"]
}
```

I have created a secret in the appropriate path (with root token):

```
$ vault kv put secret/myproject/entry1 pass=pass
Key              Value
---              -----
created_time     2022-05-11T15:06:49.658185443Z
deletion_time    n/a
destroyed        false
version          1
```

I have created a user that has been assigned the given policy:

```
$ vault token lookup
Key                 Value
---                 -----
accessor            CBnMF4i2cgadYoMNAX1YHaX6
creation_time       1652281774
creation_ttl        168h
display_name        userpass-myproject
entity_id           ad07640c-9440-c4a1-b668-ab0b8d07fe93
expire_time         2022-05-18T15:09:34.799969629Z
explicit_max_ttl    0s
id                  s.FO7PrOBdvC3KB85N46E05msi
issue_time          2022-05-11T15:09:34.799982017Z
meta                map[username:myproject]
num_uses            0
orphan              true
path                auth/userpass/login/myproject
policies            [default myproject]
renewable           true
ttl                 167h53m36s
type                service
```

However when I try to access anything (list,get), I get a 403 error:

```
$ vault kv list secret/myproject
Error listing secret/metadata/myproject: Error making API request.

URL: GET https://example.vault/v1/secret/metadata/myproject?list=true
Code: 403. Errors:

* 1 error occurred:
    * permission denied
```

```
$ vault kv get secret/myproject/entry1
Error reading secret/data/myproject/entry1: Error making API request.

URL: GET https://vault.private.gsd.sparkers.io/v1/secret/data/myproject/entry1
Code: 403. Errors:

* 1 error occurred:
    * permission denied
```

When I change the policy to this (change path to secret/*), I get access to everything:

```
$ vault policy read myproject
path "secret/*" {
  capabilities = ["create","read","update","delete","list"]
}
$ vault kv get secret/myproject/entry1
====== Metadata ======
Key              Value
---              -----
created_time     2022-05-11T15:06:49.658185443Z
deletion_time    n/a
destroyed        false
version          1

==== Data ====
Key     Value
---     -----
pass    pass
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It turns out that you need to define your policy like this:

```
path "secret/metadata/myproject/*" {
 capabilities = ["list"]
}

path "secret/data/myproject/*" {
 capabilities = ["create","read","update","delete"]
}
```

because with engine v2 kv list prepends `metadata` to your path, and kv get prepends `data` to your path.

No idea how I missed the documentation on this here: https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/secrets/kv/kv-v2:

> Writing and reading versions are prefixed with the data/ path.

Thank you @Matt Schuchard

Comment: What documentation are you referring to? The official Vault documentation for the KV2 secrets engine is rather explicit about this pathing structure for the policies. The CLI usage is indeed different, but everything else is consistent.

Comment: Indeed, I don't know how I missed it. I'll reword my answer.